# File Not Found Exception in Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, download

I am working on a laravel application where I want to download a file by clicking a button. I have stored the file in `/storage/app/public/1.pdf` and have created a symbolic link to the `public` folder. Now I tried many ways to download the file but every time, I receive error `File Not Fount Exception at path`.

I have tried the following ways for downloading the file:

```
1 -
$name = "file.pdf";
$file = storage_path(). "/app/public/1.pdf";
$headers = array(
'Content-Type: application/pdf');
return Storage::download($file, $name, $headers);

2 - 
$name = "file.pdf";
    $file = public_path(). "/storage/1.pdf";
    $headers = array(
          'Content-Type: application/pdf',
        );

    return Storage::download($file, $name, $headers);


3 - 
$name = "file.pdf";
    $file = Storage::url("1.pdf");
    $headers = array(
          'Content-Type: application/pdf',
        );

    return Storage::download($file, $name, $headers);
```

Here is the error message I get:

[image]

[image]

I tried many times but nothing worked for me. Any help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: you get 404 on `http://127.0.0.1:8000//storage/1.pdf` ?

Comment: @sta : No, I get `File Not Found at path` error

Comment: delete the storage shortcut link and generate again with `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: @sta : Still the same issue

Comment: Include the full error message in your question, and indicate which line of code it's referring to.

Comment: @miken32 : Added

Comment: Screenshots are not super helpful. Check your logs for the full error and stack trace.

Comment: @miken32 : The issue is in the path as stated by the error message. Stack Trace only shows the framework classes and functions.

Comment: Try just `return Storage::download('public/1.pdf');`

Comment: The message is pretty clear. The file is not here `C:/xampp/htdocs/wisdom2/storage/app/public/1.pdf`. Where is the actual file located?

Comment: @adam : The file is located in the same location.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ : Thanks a lot, it did work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:
[The Local Driver](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-local-driver)

> When using the `local` driver, all file operations are relative to the `root` directory defined in your `filesystems` configuration file. By default, this value is set to the `storage/app` directory.

So, if the file is stored in `storage/app/public/1.pdf`, do not pass to the Storage facade an absolute path like this one:

```
$file = storage_path(). "/app/public/1.pdf";
return Storage::download($file);
```

Instead use a path relative to the `root` directory defined in your `filesystems` configuration file:

```
$file = "public/1.pdf";
$name = "file.pdf";
return Storage::download($file, $name);
```