# Laravel 7 storeAs() for image uploading not writing file to filesystem

Tags: laravel

I have a form with image uploading in Laravel 7. These images aren't going to appear on a web page or be served in web requests; rather they are going to be included in pdfs as images for cover pages. I want to store the uploaded images in the directory `storage/uploads/manual_cover_images`.

I've created the directory

```
$ ls -lha storage/uploads/manual_cover_images/
total 8.0K
drwxrwsr-x 2 username www-data 4.0K Nov 17 15:41 .
drwxrwsr-x 3 username www-data 4.0K Nov 17 15:41 ..
-rwxrwxr-x 1 username www-data    0 Nov 17 15:41 .keep
```

Here's the relevant code from my controller:

```
public function editManual(Request $request, $manual_id) {
    if ( $request->method() == 'POST' ) {
        if ($request->hasFile('cover_image')) {
           if ($request->file('cover_image')->isValid()) {
               $result = $request->cover_image->storeAs('storage/uploads/manual_cover_images',
                    $request->cover_image->getClientOriginalName() );
            }
        }
    }

...
}
```

I've tried the path for the first argument for `storeAs()` both with and without a leading slash. However, I've not been able to get the uploaded image to be saved on the filesystem.

The image passes `hasFile()` and `isValid()`, so it seems like the actual upload is coming through on the request. For troubleshooting, I've been debugging the output of the `saveAs()` method. The result that I see in the browser is just the file path that I specified in the arguments:

```
^ "storage/uploads/manual_cover_images/good doggo.jpg"
```

However when I look at the filesystem, my image isn't there:

```
$ ls -lha storage/uploads/manual_cover_images/
total 8.0K
drwxrwsr-x 2 username www-data 4.0K Nov 17 15:41 .
drwxrwsr-x 3 username www-data 4.0K Nov 17 15:41 ..
-rwxrwxr-x 1 username www-data    0 Nov 17 15:41 .keep
```

How do I have an uploaded image file to a directory that I specify?

Comment: the disk's root isn't the root of the application its the `storage/app` folder

Comment: Based on your directory structure, I think the easier way is to create a new disk, declare the root in `/storage/uploads`, and use the Storage Facade passing to it a path relative to the directory you declared as root in config/filesystems. Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64774064/7498116) if it helps